# Uncaught TypeError Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, typeerror

I am trying to modify images using button click.
The js is supposed to update the image style on button click but it gives error.
But when I try the same on my console it works.

This is my HTML Code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Image Modifier</title>
    <style>
        body{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        img{
            width: 50%;
            filter: initial;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="pic" src="nature.jpg">
    <button id="contrast" onclick="cont()">Contrast</button>
    <button id="grayscale" onclick="gray()">Grayscale</button>
    <button id="invert" onclick="inv()">Invert</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image = document.getElementById('pic')
        function cont(image) {
            image.style.filter="contrast(180%)";
        }
        function gray(image) {
            image.style.filter="grayscale(100%)";
        }
        function inv(image) {
            image.style.filter="invert(100%)";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It gives me the below error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at cont (first.html:26)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (first.html:19)
cont @ first.html:26
onclick @ first.html:19

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at gray (first.html:29)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (first.html:20)
gray @ first.html:29
onclick @ first.html:20

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
    at inv (first.html:32)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (first.html:21)
```

Comment: Don't add `image` as a parameter when you are not passing any parameters. It is shadowing the `var image` you declare above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're passing an `image` variable to each function, which doesn't exist, thus returning undefined

```js
var image = document.getElementById('pic')

function cont() {
  image.style.filter = "contrast(180%)";
}

function gray() {
  image.style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
}

function inv() {
  image.style.filter = "invert(100%)";
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  width: 50%;
  filter: initial;
}
```

```html
<img id="pic" src="https://static.passeportsante.net/680x357/i93408-.jpeg">
<button id="contrast" onclick="cont()">Contrast</button>
<button id="grayscale" onclick="gray()">Grayscale</button>
<button id="invert" onclick="inv()">Invert</button>
```

Comment: But I am declaring var image which has scope global so shouldn't I be able to pass it as a parameter.

Comment: You're not passing it as parameter in your code, `onclick="cont()"`, where are you passing it? Not here anyway. So `function cont(image)` has `image` as undefined, as it's waiting for an argument that doesn't exist, and in the same time as it has the same name as the global variable it's reinitialize it inside the function. You need to go and read about how functions work, this is basic syntax.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use const instead of var

const image = document.getElementById('pic')

or define your variable inside each function with "let"

```
function cont(image) {
  let image = document.getElementById('pic')
  image.style.filter = "contrast(180%)";
}

function gray(image) {
  let image = document.getElementById('pic')
  image.style.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
}

function inv(image) {
  let image = document.getElementById('pic')
  image.style.filter = "invert(100%)";
}
```

Comment: "_Try to use const instead of var_" How is that going to make a difference?